# show and hide contact form react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a `<ContactUs />` component which has my contact us form. i want to show and hide that component when `get in touch` button in the `<navbar />` component is clicked.

> I tried setState for showContact (in `<contactUs />`) it works in contactUs but i cant change the state from `<navbar />` .

contactUs.js

```
 const [showContact, setShowContact] = useState(false);

 return <div className={`contact-us-container  ${showContact ? "shown" : ""}`}>
   // form
 </div>
```

Navbar.js

```
 <a href="#" className="navbar-item cta-button" onClick={??}>Get in touch</a> //should change showContact
```

App.js

```
<navbar />
<home /> // homepage content
<contactUs />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply update your existing code like this and pass the props from `App.js` to other files

***contactUs.js***

```js
 import { Fragment } from "react";

 export default function ContactUS({ showContact }){
   return (
     <Fragment>
       { showContact ? (
         <div className="contact-us-container">
           // form
         </div>
       ):("") }
     </Fragment>
   );
 }
```

***navbar.js***

```js
import { Fragment } from "react";

 export default function NavBar({ setShowContact }){
   return (
     <Fragment>
        <a href="#" className="navbar-item cta-button" onClick={ () => setShowContact(true) }>Get in touch</a>
     </Fragment>
   );
 }
```

***app.js***

```js
 import Home from "path/to/Home ";
 import NavBar from "path/to/Navbar";
 import ContactUS from "path/to/ContactUS ";
 import { Fragment, useState } from "react";

 export default function App(){
   const [showContact, setShowContact] = useState(false);

   return (
     <Fragment>
        <NavBar setShowContact={setShowContact} />
        <Home />
        <ContactUS showContact={showContact} />
     </Fragment>
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Navbar and contact us form inside home component and lift up state and pass showContact from parent

```
in Home component 


  const [showContact , setshowContact] = useState(false);
    <navbar setShowContact = {setShowContact}/>
    <contactUs showContact={showContact} />
    
    in Navbar component 
    const {setShowContact} = props
     <a href="#" className="navbar-item cta-button" onClick={() => setshowContact(false)}>Get in touch</a> //should change showContact
```

Comment: In the navbar, you also need the setShowContact method, so you change the state of showContact, right ?

Comment: Yes you are correct I missed setState method

Comment: the onClick should rather look like : onClick={() => setShowContact(true)}

Comment: Yes , but I think both are similar way of function as second is an implementation of arrow function. We can use Both functions

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I think the first parenthesis are required if you want to pass a parameter to the function

Comment: yes  , if we call function passing using paramters we should use arrow funtions my bad. I was little confused by the syntax of arrow function

Comment: React components need to be PascalCase: `NavBar` and `ContactUs`.

Comment: Yes Andy , as I used component given by question so that the narrator can understand it

Answer (score 1):

contactUs.js

```
export default function ContactUs() {
  return <div>Contact us form here</div>
}
```

navbar.js

```
export default function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <nav>
      ...
      {props && props.showContactForm
        ? <button onClick={() => props.setShowContactForm(false)}>Hide contact us</button>
        : <button onClick={() => props.setShowContactForm(true)}>Show contact us</button>
      }
    </nav>
  )
}
```

home.js

```
export default function Home() {
  const [showContactForm, setShowContactForm] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <Navbar showContactForm={showContactForm} setShowContactForm={setShowContactForm} />
      {showContactForm && <ContactUs />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use [react router](https://reactrouter.com/), in order to navigate to the  component. So whenever you click on Get in touch button, you navigate to the `ContactUs` component, with something like this (instead of the `a` that you have):

```
<Link to="/contactUs">Get in touch</Link>
```

You will also need some route definition at the root of your App, to handle the rooting

Comment: contactus is a popup form which i want to show on click of button. router wont help

Comment: if it is popup then you can use react bootstrap modal and it provides you state method ,and then you can lift up state or use usecontext hook and wrap all needed state with a wrapper component and pass it to needed component

Comment: Modals/pop-ups are easy enough to create in React [using a portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) @BuildThough. You don't have to load in a whole separate library to get that functionality.

Comment: Yes @Andy Modal is far better option

Answer (score 0):

For rendering, you can render it like this in the render function - `{showContact && <ContactUs />}` or the condition that you already mentioned in your answer

i.e-  `` return <div className={`contact-us-container  ${showContact ? "shown" : ""}`}> // form </div> ``

To change it's state from navbar, you can have to pass the `setShowContact` function as a prop to `<navbar />` component like shown below.

``  ```

Now inside the navbar component you can use props.setShowContact(true/false) to show or hide the contact form.

Answer (score 0):

A modal might be useful in this case. For those [we use a React portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). It positions the modal outside of the DOM hierarchy of the parent element. You can add in all the HTML you want. They're really useful for forms.

> A typical use case for portals is when a parent component has an overflow: hidden or z-index style, but you need the child to visually “break out” of its container. For example, dialogs, hovercards, and tooltips.

(Also pop-ups and modals.)

The parent component should manage the state of the modal (open or closed), so we need to pass down a handler to both the `Nav` and `ContactUs` components.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Create the modal component which accepts two handlers,
// and "children" which is the HTML you want to show
function Modal({ isOpen, onClose, children }) {
  if (!isOpen) return null;
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(    
    <div className="modal">
      {children}
      <button
        className="closemodal"
        onClick={onClose}
      >Close
      </button>
    </div>,
    document.body
  );
}

// Pass in the handler to the Nav component
function Nav({ handleModal }) {
  return (
    <nav>
      <a onClick={handleModal}>Get in touch</a>
    </nav>
  );
}

// ContactUs builds the form within the modal
// We pass in the showModal state, and the handler
function ContactUs({ showModal, handleModal }) {
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={showModal} onClose={handleModal}>
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Email</legend>
        <input type="email" />
        <button
          className="send"
          type="button"
        >Send</button>
      </fieldset>
    </Modal>
  );
}

function Example() {

  const [ showModal, setShowModal ] = useState(false);

  // Our main handler for the modal. It simply
  // toggles between true and false
  function handleModal() {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav handleModal={handleModal} />
      <ContactUs
        showModal={showModal}
        handleModal={handleModal}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
nav { padding: 1em; margin: 0.2em; background-color: #efefef; }
nav a { border: 2px solid #454545; padding: 0.25em; }
nav a:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #dfdfdf; }
.modal { position: fixed; inset: 0; background-color: white; margin: 0.5em; border: 2px solid #343434; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; overflow-y:scroll; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; z-index: 999; }
fieldset { margin-bottom: 1em; background-color: #efefef; }
.closemodal { padding: 0.5em; background-color: #336699; color: white; }
.send { background-color: #44aa77; color: white; }
.closemodal:hover, .send:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```