# How to add fade in fade out small popup using React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, popup

I want a popup like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uazuy.png)

I have seen this question - [How to add a simple popup in REACT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857789/how-to-add-a-simple-popup-in-react/71859199#71859199), but I don't want such a big popup and I want it to be reusable. Currently, it is not. Is there a way to make the popup such as in the image above? It would help out a lot, thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857789/how-to-add-a-simple-popup-in-react/71859199#71859199 recreate this modal but it is not reusable

Comment: you can make it reusable by passing down props

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.