# How to make pop up with reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How to make a pop-up information box when you click an element.
Example like this image :
[image: Before Click]

[image: After Click]

Like this image, you click "View all study equipment" an  element and then get that pop-up for more information.

This is my code :

```
<>
  <div className="description-container">
    <div className="nav-tab">
      <ul className="description-tab">
        <li>
          <a href="/" className="active">
            Class Description
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">Testimony</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">FAQ</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="description-info">
    <div className="desc-list">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>
      Websites in today's era have become a major need that cannot be
      ignored. All business or education sectors can use the website as a
      tool for promotion, exchange of information, and others. Based on data
      from the World Wide Web Technology Surveys, of all active websites,
      88.2% use HTML, 95.6% use CSS and 95% use JavaScript. This class
      thoroughly discusses the basics of HTML, CSS and JavaScript as the
      three foundations of website creation.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>The web is a platform that can be accessed through many kinds of devices. This is an advantage if you develop Web-based applications.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Web development does not require a computer/laptop that has high specifications, so it is not an obstacle for those of you who do not have a capable device.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>The website is a platform that is reached by search engines such as Google Search, so the website is suitable as a medium for promoting business or content.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Developing a website includes development that is easy to maintain and easy to publish.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="specs-description-info">
        <h4>Learning Equipment</h4>
        <h5><i class="fas fa-microchip"></i>Processor</h5>
        <span>Intel Celeron (Core i3 and above Recommended)</span>
        <h4>Tools yang dibutuhkan untuk belajar:</h4>
        <span><i class="fad fa-window"></i>Web Browser (Google Chrome atau Mozilla Firefox)</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a className="equip_info" href="/">View all study equipment</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="sub-border-description-info">
        <h3>Student Targets and Goals :</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>This class is intended for beginners who want to start their career in the field of web development (web creation) and need a strong foundation or foundation before studying deeper in the web field, with reference to international standards owned by Google Developers.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Classes can be attended by students who are IT literate so it is mandatory to have and be able to operate a computer well.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>This class is designed for beginners so there are no prerequisites in prior understanding of programming.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Students must be able to learn independently, be committed, really have curiosity, and be interested in the subject matter, because no matter how good this class material is, it will not be useful without students' seriousness to learn, practice, and try.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="subdescription-info">
        <h3>General and Specific Objectives of the Training :</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>At the end of the training, participants can create a simple website using programming code that complies with global standards.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Build a website using simple HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Implement a good website structure using standard semantic HTML.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Demonstrating the preparation of website layouts using float or flexbox techniques.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</>
```

Maybe you can share how to make it with React Javascript and CSS too.
This is using newest react.
Thank You

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/reactjs-popup

Comment: I will recommend you use libraries instead reinvent the wheel here one: https://react-popup.elazizi.com. but you can look for one that fit your purpose better.

Comment: [Use a portal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71436694/1377002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you can do is use the useState hook. Let me explain:

first, import the usestate hook, check the react docs on how to do that, but if youre using vs code it will probably do that for you if you type the next part -->

this will create a state oject (popup) with the default value of false, that can be altered by the togglepopup function:

```
const [popup, togglepopup] = useState(false);
```

Then in your button/element you want to use to toggle the popup write:

```
onClick={togglepopup(!popup)}
```

this will change the current popup value to the oposite value, e.x. false => true, true => false.

then just create a piece of javascript that looks like this:

```
{popup && <div className={'popup-bg'}>
<div className={'popup'}></div></div>}
```

now just set the popup-bg in your stylesheet to position: fixed, width: 100vw, height: 100vw, display: flex, align-items: center, justify-content: center, backdropfilter: blur(10px);

and now it will center your popup div.

Comment: one thing to remember is that you should declare the const usestate hook inside of your class/function, but outside the return(...);

Comment: I have put all CSS, const, and trigger but the javascript one is kinda confusing,
I put it like this from className="specs-description-info"

<button className="equip_info" onClick={togglepopup(!popup)}>View all study equipment</button>
            {popup && <div className={'popup-bg'}>
              <div className={'popup'}></div></div>}

If I make that, the preview is blank, all of it

Comment: could you change the onClick to: onClick={() =>{togglepopup(!popup)}}, and then share a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, no blank anymore but there is no popup when I clicked
https://pastebin.com/d8hkwexM

Comment: ahh, lastly add _z-index: 255;_ to the css properties of your popup

Comment: it does pop up, but can't be close because of the background and should make some close button one, and the pop up itself is not centered but it does work out still not perfect yet, if I use fixed, it will not show any popup, if I make absolute position it will show up. And if could how to do like the pop up just like a small box with background dim only not blur.

https://pastebin.com/0qs7ub4Z js
https://pastebin.com/80ixU2Z3 css